# frame rate for a video texture of an object

Tags: video, frame-rate

Hey I'm not familiar with Blender, but for a university project I have to use Blender... I created an object and inserted a video as a texture, but now the video runs very slow and laggy. I tried to change the frame rate to a higher fps, but nothing has changed. I watched this tutorial but his video plays normally: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1COCnMUIhQ&t=252s

Thanks in advance.

here are my video settings :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

240 FPS seems a bit extreme. 120 FPS is already quite a high framerate.

Anyway, you can try changing the Playback Sync mode from "Play every frame" to "Frame Dropping". The video won't run smoother, but will play at the target FPS, so at the correct timing.

This setting can be found in the Timeline Editor, under the Playback menu.
[Timeline documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/timeline.html)

Keep it mind that this only affects the Viewport, so it's more confortable to work with. After you render the frames to a video format like FFMpeg, the exported video should run smoothly anyway.